# Obtain B to minimize $\|\boldsymbol{X}-\boldsymbol{B}\|_{\boldsymbol{F}}^{2}$ with constraint on the spectral norm of B to be ≤ 1

Tags: matrices, optimization, svd, matrix-norms

I stumbled upon this problem where I have to

I want to obtain B such that we Minimize $\|\boldsymbol{X}-\boldsymbol{B}\|_{\boldsymbol{F}}^{2}$ subject to the constraint
that the spectral norm of  is less than or equal to one.

I tried to proceed using the SVD decomposition and trying to involve some inequalities of norms. but with no result.
Any suggestions??

Comment: This can easily be solved as a convex optimization problem with an SDP constraint.  Are you looking for that convex optimization formulation of the problem or hoping for a closed form solution?

Comment: I'd guess that you can just set the singular values of $X$ that are greater than $1$ equal to $1$.

Comment: I would like to solve it in close form in a sense that I want to obtain B

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Wikipedia, the [Frobenius norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Frobenius_norm) is equivalent to $\displaystyle \Vert X-B\Vert_F^2=\sum_{i=1}^{min(m,n)}\sigma_i^2(X-B)$

Write X in its svd form $X=\sum_i\lambda_iu_iv_i^T$

Write B as $\sum_ib_iu_iv_i^T$

Then $X-B=\sum_i(\lambda_i-b_i)u_iv_i^T$

Take $b_i=min\{\lambda_i, 1\}$

Then this achieves the minimum frobenius norm.

Disclaimer: not sure if this works.

Comment: This does work, but I don't find the argument here to be very convincing- you haven't addressed why B can be written using the same singular vectors as X.  A more rigorous approach would be to show that the Frobenius norm is invariant under orthogonal transformations and then transform X to diagonal form by using U and V from its SVD.

Comment: This is indeed correct. A proof can be found [here](https://doi.org/10.13001/1081-3810.1551) (lemma 2.2).